# Upsert with attribute included updated_at

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I want to make some script backfill data from an old database to a new database, with `gorm` as it ORM, and I want to upsert using `FirstOrCreate`, below are the attributes and query used:

```
user {
  ID: someid,
  Name: somename,
  .
  .
  .
  CreatedAt: time.Time,
  UpdatedAt: 2020-03-24 17:57:00,
}

err = db.Where(user{ID: someid}).Assign(user).FirstOrCreate(&user)
```

I want in new database, the data is as it is (`updated_at = 2020-03-24 17:57:00`) but I got `updated_at` is `time.Now()`

How can I upsert the data with `updated_at` is updated as I send it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrCreate()` calls `Updates()` when data exist with given `ID`.
`Updates()` operation will perform the model's `BeforeUpdate`, `AfterUpdate` method, update its `UpdatedAt` timestamp, save its Associations when updaing, if you don't want to call them, you could use `UpdateColumn`, `UpdateColumns` with separate `Create` operation when data is not exist.

Ref: [Gorm official document about update](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html)

Comment: yes its solved, although it has to use workaround instead of using the same method, thanks