# Gorm save without updating updated_at column

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I noticed when calling the db.Save() method, the column updated_at also gets updated. Have checked the docs and it seems that way as well: https://gorm.io/docs/update.html

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60829707/13860

Comment: @Flimzy i don't want to replace db.Save() method since the object has nested objects inside. I only want certain objects to have the column updated_at updated that i specify explicitly prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution by adding the following line after initializing db connection:

```
db.GetConnection().Callback().Update().Remove("gorm:update_time_stamp")
```

I found this when checking through the following code:
https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/jinzhu/gorm/-/blob/callback_update.go#L20:75

There are multiple callbacks being called by default when an Update is done. So the fix was to remove it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but your solution does not work for me :-( "callback_update.go" does not exist in https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm. What solution are you using atm?

Comment: hi @some-user, above solution is the one i'm using.
for your case, maybe you can have a look at this https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/go-gorm/gorm/-/blob/callbacks/callbacks.go?L65:22

Comment: Thanks for coming back on that. What is your `db` object? `gorm.DB`? `GetConnection()` does not exists there. Neither does the "gorm:update_time_stamp" callback :-(